# My IDE runs tests slower when in a different workspace

Tags: macos, java, spaces

I am developing a server-side application using Java and OSX and quite often I have to run a rather large test suite to make sure everything is alright. I am using IntelliJ IDEA (Java-based IDE).

When I use one workspace only, tests finish in about ~3 minutes no matter whether the IDE has focus or not. It just has to be in the same workspace.

When I move the IDE to a different workspace (so I'd have 2 workspaces) or into fullscreen mode (which essentially creates a new workspace), test execution is ~100% slower (takes about 6 minutes).

When I keep the focus in the second workspace for the whole execution time period, we're back to ~3 minutes.

This is really puzzling to me. I measured it using various number of workspaces and various number of applications per workspace, same results.

---

Clarification from the discussion from the comments, to avoid confusion:

> If the focus in in the workspace with the IDE or full-screen IDE, it's fast. Once the focus is on a different workspace (so the IDE is either on a different workspace or in a full-screen mode (but with no focus)) then it is slower.

Comment: 100% slower is dead you mean runs at 50% speed or the one workspace is 100% faster

Comment: @Mark it means that it runs at 50% speed

Comment: I worked  out that is what you meant but you have not written what you meant

Comment: more importantly as per comments in answer the full screen timing seems to conflict with running not having focus

Comment: Fullscreen is just a different workspace, right? So nothing changes here - if you're focused in the fullscreen app it's fast, if you're not it's slow. Same for workspaces.

Comment: However your question says that is slow when in fullscreen and not clear you are out of focus (how can you do that surely full screen has nothing else that can be in focus)

Answer (score -1):

It part of OS X itself to optimize the resources and to keep wise balance between foreground process and background tasks. Operating system devotes more resources to the active workspace, and to put less CPU processing capacity to the background tasks.

Benefits are obvious:

- the higher responsiveness for user of the system in the overall for the foreground process;
- and less CPU load (less heat is produced, CPU fan is quiet), lower impact on the battery life.

It should be clearly visible with *Activity Monitor* App, how much power system devotes to specific process.

Comment: But if OP is in full screen he says it is slower

Comment: @Mark, no, OP said, that when the work-space kept focused - it backs to normal, to regular execution time. And it's exactly about that.

Comment: "When I move the IDE to a different workspace (so I'd have 2 workspaces) or into fullscreen mode " so it is also in fullscreen mode

Comment: @Mark, and how about the next line? *> When I keep the **focus** in the second workspace for the whole execution time period, **we're back to ~3 minutes.***

Comment: @Xorty please look at the comments above and edit you question to clarify the situation as the question is inconsistent

Comment: @Mark, any reasons for the down-vote from your side?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - it is as Farside says, if the focus in in the workspace with the IDE or fullscreen IDE, it's fast. Once the focus is on a different workspace (so the IDE is either on a different workspace or in a fullscreen mode (but with no focus)) then it is slower.

Comment: @Mark, so the understanding was correct. So why I gotten down-vote from you, can you elaborate on it may be?